# RSA: number of pairs $(e,d)$ such that $(e,n)$ and $(d,n)$ are public/private keys

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I would like to show the following: Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd primes and $n = pq$, then $\varphi(\lambda(n))$ is the number of pairs $(e,d)$ such that $(e,n)$ and $(d,n)$ are public/private keys of an RSA cryptosystem and that $2 \leq \varphi(\lambda(n)) < \lambda(n)/2$, where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function and $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

I don't really know how to start... can someone help me with this, please?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get much attention here, I suggest you flag your question and ask for it to be moved to [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). This could be a good question there too.